# Enable identity aware proxy can control acess to your openAPI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-api-nodejs-client

Securing my open API which is with Nodejs & Google Cloud Endpoints. So if I enable identity-aware proxy then can I control the secure my open API's

Also, I wanna give the opeAPI access to my premium members only is there any other solution...??

Answer (score 0):

What I'm trying to understand is why you are attempting to use IAP when you can use Cloud Endpoints themselves to restrict API access. You can even do it a Google Group level.

Here you can read more about [Endpoints API control](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/control-api-access)

And I think this is useful as well, it's an article on using [API Authentication with IAP](https://blog.realkinetic.com/api-authentication-with-gcp-identity-aware-proxy-3a4147b30770).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @stefan it will be helpfull.

Comment: Hey if you think this solved your issue, please accept the answer to give it more visibility and let other users know this helped you.